# Excel VBA Call Shell with quotes in string

Tags: vba, excel, shell, quotes, double-quotes

I don't really know how to deal with my problem.
So what i want is:

```
Call Shell("C:\Temp\Zint\zint.exe -d "1234"",vbNormalFocus)
```

I use this command in the windows command line: C:\Temp\Zint\zint.exe -d "1234"

It works only when the numbers are given between quotes.

I was unable to deal with the quotes, so please be so kinde to explain me how should i use them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In VBA quotes are escaped by doubling them up:

```
Call Shell("C:\Temp\Zint\zint.exe -d ""1234""",vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: Thanks! It did not work but i've found the solution... i've spent my whole day solving it...
Call Shell("C:\Temp\Zint\zint.exe" & " " & "-d" & Chr(34) & "1234" & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)

Comment: @Dominik you answer is the same as what Tim posted here :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - **Maybe** getting rid of the space in `-d "1234"` was required to get it to work, but there certainly is nothing in the question to indicate that it shouldn't be there, so I agree that Tim's answer is better than the OP's self-answer

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
Call Shell("C:\Temp\Zint\zint.exe" & " " & "-d" & Chr(34) & "1234" & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as my suggestion (but more complex IMHO) except you now have no space between the `-d` and "1234"

Comment: If getting rid of the space between `-d` and `"1234"` was required to get the code to work, please update the question to say something like " 
 When I use this command in the windows command line: `C:\Temp\Zint\zint.exe -d "1234"` it doesn't work, but `C:\Temp\Zint\zint.exe -d"1234"` does work  "